# html - issue on using frameset with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, frame, frameset

I have a popup window containing a `frameset` with two frames.
In FireFox and Chrome I can resize widths of both frames with the mouse but in IE9 it's not possible.

How can I resolve this issue?

```
<frameset cols="275,*" frameborder="5" border="5" framespacing="0">

     <frame name="title2" src="path/test.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto">


     <frame style="overflow-x:hidden;" name="title2" src="path/test.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto">

</frameset>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the issue by removing attributs `frameborder`, `border` and `framespacing` from `frameset` .

Comment: I had to change from framespaing="0" to framespacing="2"